# grep command in json file

Tags: unix, grep

I am using grep command in a multiple json file which has content like this: 
 "Verdict": {
                "Severity": "-1",
                "Description": "Some description" Reputation"

}

I want  look for word Verdict and if it matches ,get the Severity number.
So far I used:

"grep -A 2 -R \"Verdict\" path\to\file*.json\"|grep Severity|cut -d \":\" -f2|tr -d \",\"|tr -d \\"|tr -d \" \""

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, provide a proper example. Also `grep` is not the right tool for this job. Use a syntax aware parser like `jq`

Comment: You'd better use a JSON library, regular expressions are a great tool, but not the proper choice for structured data like JSON.

Comment: Actullay I am using this grep in a python script

Comment: how about something like: cat file.json | grep "Verdict" | grep -o '[-[:digit:]]*'